# Why does the 'exchange interaction' in ferromagnetism favour parallel spins of electrons? Shouldn't the pauli exclusion principle hold?

Tags: pauli-exclusion-principle, ferromagnetism

I am trying to grasp the concept of the "exchange interaction" in ferromagnetism, specifically why it favors the parallel alignment of electron spins. Intuitively, one might expect the Pauli Exclusion Principle to promote antiparallel alignment. Since the Pauli exclusion principle states that no two identical fermions (such as electrons) can occupy the same quantum state simultaneously.Can someone provide a detailed explanation of why the exchange interaction tends to favor parallel spins despite the Pauli Exclusion Principle?

Comment: You should not be appealing to PEP; what is happening beneath PEP is that there is fermion (skew-)symmetry, and it is precisely because of this skew-symmetry that the exchange term even appears at all. So PEP part is already completely handled. Now, yes, "no two identical fermions can occupy the same quantum state simultaneously", but those are electrons ostensibly centred at different atoms, or are at different energy levels. There is thus no problem with PEP.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer:

When electrons have parallel spins (occupying the same orbital state), they experience a significant energy decrease because the Pauli exclusion principle prevents them from getting too close due to their identical quantum states. The electrostatic interaction between these electrons at different spatial separations results in an energy difference, and this energy difference is quantified by the exchange energy term. The exchange energy can be relatively large, around 1 electronvolt (eV), which is significantly greater than the energy associated with the direct magnetic interaction between neighboring atomic spins (about 10^−4eV).

It's important to note that the exchange effect is short-range, and the Ising model typically considers interactions only between nearest neighbors, which is a realistic approximation. When the spins are anti-aligned (have opposite directions), they can be close together because they occupy different quantum states. In this case, there is electrostatic repulsion between them.

On the other hand, when the spins are aligned, they cannot approach each other closely due to the Pauli exclusion principle, resulting in a weaker electrostatic repulsion. Consequently, it is energetically favorable for spins to be in a parallel alignment. The energy difference between parallel and anti-parallel alignments is mainly electrostatic in origin and can be quite substantial, highlighting the dominant role of the Pauli exclusion principle in determining the preferred spin configurations.